# Прослушивание ввода

Tags: android, kotlin

Собственно вопрос производен заголовку - как слушать ввод?

Есть ли какой-то аналог onInput (события input html/js)?
Если нет - то как получать событие - ввод/стирание чего-то в/из поле ввода?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для прослушивания ввода в `EditText` используется `TextWatcher`.
Пример:

```
edit_text.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable?) {
            sum_input_view.error = null
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
        }
    })
```

Comment: Спасибо, не видел такой слушатель в учебниках, а сам не догадался .add*smthng*Listener поискать, только .set*smthng*Listener смотрел.